# Java script printing out a blank page

Tags: javascript

I have the following java script code

```
  $("#btn_Print").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var printWindow = window.open("../private/analysisPrint.htm");
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
            return false;
        });
```

and the analysisPrint.htm page contains.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html

     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4>
                Print</h4>
                First print page
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem I am having is that I am always getting a blank page being printed. When i open the page directly and print its fine.

Any Ideas

Comment: You may have to wait for the page to be done loading first.

Comment: If you remove the print() and close() calls, does it open the window and load the document correctly?

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo, yep it loads correctly. and if I then print from the browser menu its fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (and probably should) wait for the page to load completely (including images):

```
var printWindow = window.open("../private/analysisPrint.htm");
$(printWindow).on('load', function() {
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
});
```